# SSRS line chart - X Axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a series of prices over a daily period. In SSRS, I've plotted these against a line chart.
For the X axis, I'm wanting a custom display where for the first day of the month (except Jan) to show the month name, and the first month to show the year.

So it should look like
2023 J F M A etc.

I've done this calculation via the DB side (let's call this column XAxisLabel). The actual value that is plotted is called Date. I've put Date against the Category Group and set the label expression on the Category Group to this XAxisLabel column. I've also set the Label interval as 1 on the XAxisLabel. The problem is when I run the report, the output is all unrecognizable and "gibberish".

However, it seems to work if I make sure the XAxisLabel doesn't have any blank values, but this means the scale won't show correctly if I populate every value.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like it should work (assUme-ing Date is a DATE and the Labels are 1:1 matches). Maybe a pic of the result would help figure it out. If you've changed the chart a few times, try creating a new chart with the same properties.